# How can I render a component in Blazor that is defined as object?

Tags: c#, blazor

I have the following code:

```
<div>
@if (Components != null && Components.Count != 0) {
   foreach (ComponentBase child in Components) {
      // Render the child component here
   }
}
</div>
```

How do I use RenderFragment to render the child object? The child object is a template component that inherits other classes (with ComponentBase on top).

The problem is that the child object already is set with all its parameters, so I don't want to set all the RenderFragment parameters again using the object data.

Things I tried inside the foreach loop but did not work:

```
foreach (ComponentBase child in Components) {
  @child // <-- does render the class text
}

foreach (ComponentBase child in Components) {
  <ComponentBase>@child</ComponentBase> // <-- error
}

foreach (ComponentBase child in Components) {
  RenderFragment renderChild = (builder) => { builder.OpenComponent(0, child.GetType()); builder.CloseComponent(); };
@renderChild; // <-- I want to render the child object as this does nothing
}
```

Comment: "The problem is that the child object already is set with all its parameters" - that sounds like a problem - Blazor expects to create and initialise all components - and to manage their parameters. If you instantiate yourself and populate the parameters, you are breaking the core rendering system.

Comment: See this example as a container holding a specific component. So instead of using <ButtonComponent><ButtonComponent/> and its parameters, I have a <ContainerComponent><ContainerComponent/> which can contain multiple ButtonComponents in a list. This is required for certain css positioning and setting the absolute style of the main container.

Comment: It's still not clear what you want to achieve - and your last comment doesn't change that - are you creating instances of components through code?

Comment: Yes. And I want to somehow render these instances dynamicly

Comment: Ok, that's not supported - you need to let Blazor create instances of your components and track the parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is almost the equivelent of the upcoming DynamicComponent in .net6

You can pass either the type via `Type` or the typename via `TypeString`

```
public class ComponentView : ComponentBase
{
    [Parameter]
    public Type Type { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public string TypeString { get; set; }

    private Dictionary<string, object> parameters;

    [Parameter]
    public Dictionary<string, string> Values { get; set; }

    protected override void OnParametersSet()
    {
        if (Values is null) {
            parameters = null;
        }
        else {
            parameters = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            foreach (var pair in Values) {
                parameters[pair.Key] = pair.Value;
            }
        }
        base.OnParametersSet();
    }



    protected override void BuildRenderTree(RenderTreeBuilder builder)
    {
        if (Type is null) {
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(TypeString)) {
                throw new Exception("You must use either Type or the TypeString paramater");
            }
            Type = Type.GetType(TypeString);
        }

        if (Type is not null) {
            builder.OpenComponent(1, Type);

            if (parameters is not null) {
                builder.AddMultipleAttributes(2, parameters);
            }
            builder.CloseComponent();
        }
        base.BuildRenderTree(builder);
    }
}
```

From this [repo](https://github.com/BrianLParker/ComponentViewer)

Comment: That surely does look good, but how can I get existing parameters from my component instance as Dictionary to pass it to the BuildRenderTree?

Comment: @Dagovax It has a paramater called `Values` wich is `Dictionary<string,string>`. If you go back in the commits you will see it was `Parameters`  `Dictionary<string,object>`.  I was asked to change it to <string, string> for a use case. if you run the demo you will see I pass different parameters.

Comment: I was about to post a very similar answer, but  Brian beat me to it.  To answer your question, you can't "render" an existing instance of a component.  The Renderer instantiates the provided `type` , calls `Attach` when it attaches it to the Render Tree, and then passing in the parameters by calling `SetParametersAsync`.

Comment: As @MrCakaShaunCurtis pointed out the crux of the component is the final `if` block at the bottom of the code block.

Comment: You should also probably test the defined `Type` implements `IComponent` - all  render components must implement this interface.  Something like `if (!Type.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(IComponent)))  throw new Exception($" {component.ComponentType.Name} must implement IComponent.");`
.